# How to kill application using its name?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get package names from application name ??
for e.g if app name is location , can I get its package name com.android.location, so that I can kill it using

am.killBackgroundProcesses(package name)

or someone knows any function directly to kill using app name. any other suggestions ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will get all running process and go through all of them to find the one with the specified name and kill the process.

```
String nameOfProcess = "location";
ActivityManager  manager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
{
    if (process.processName.contains(nameOfProcess))
    {
        // Ends the app
        manager.restartPackage(process.processName);
        break;
    }
}
```

To use this method, you will need the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: restartPackage() is deprecated. Use killBackgroundProcesses() instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method of doing this. You can scan through all the packages, and get their application labels, and kill those whichever you wish.

[PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel%28android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo%29)

There are quite a few methods which you can use for this.