# Android hacking : where is the methods/functions related to app killing

Tags: android

If you are familiar with the Android source code, could you help me point out the methods/functions related to app/process killing used by Android?

A cross reference link would be best.

Comment: you shouldn't kill your application (or anyone else) leave the OS to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on another stack overflow article. It goes through the list of running processes/apps and kills based on name:

```
String nameOfProcess = "location";
ActivityManager  manager =(ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);   

List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
{
  if (process.processName.contains(nameOfProcess))
 {
    // Ends the app
    manager.restartPackage(process.processName);
    break;
  }
}
```

You also need the following permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
```

Reference: [How to kill application using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623961/how-to-kill-application-using-its-name)